# How to return a specific output to a variable using raw query in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a variable which needed a value from a specific query

> $player_id_owner = $this->Player->fetchAll('Select id from player
>   where name = ?',    array($name));

```
 $player_id_owner = ($this->Player->find('all', array(
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                    'conditions' => array('Player.name' => '$name')
                    )));
```

i tried both raw query and cakephp find but both of them returns only "array"

have i forgotten something? how can i access the expected result from query? thanks

Comment: CakePHP returns (almost) everything in arrays, you should do var_dump ( $player_id_owner ); to see what's in there, most likely an array holding the ID.

Comment: Please refer : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: Thanks, but still i can't find how, can you give me sample code on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
'Player.name' => '$name'
```

is not valid PHP code, at least not for what you try to do.
Don't escape variables as strings:

```
'Player.name' => $name
```

You could have easily seen that by checking the resulting query in the debug kit or the bottom of the view.

And most likely you would want to use `find('first', ...)` as documented if you only expect a single entry here.

Last but not least:
You most likely just lack basic debugging skills. Don't echo it, as it is indeed an array. Never do that with unknown variables as they often are everything but a basic string. 
Use `debug()` to see whats inside and then properly echo what you see, e.g. `echo $player['Player']['name'];`.

Bear in mind that stringish output should be secured by h() on output:

```
echo h($player['Player']['name']);
```

Comment: Sorry, i have tried that before but still that's not my problem. What i want is to pass the result of my query to my variable. thanks

Comment: Thanks mark, i have tried find first but still it also doesn't pass the value to my variable, and about the debugging skills yes you're correct im new to cakephp and i only use notepad for my coding so im a bit behind for that. hope you'll understand me.

Comment: Whats the output of `debug($player);`? What doesnt work with `$id = $player['Player']['id'];`?

Comment: thanks mark but they got this error
using $id = $player['Player']['id']; 
Notice (8): Undefined variable: player [APP/Controller/ActivitiesController.php, line 311

while using debug($player_id_owner);
it returns this. array()

Comment: Ähm, you are aware that I used $player just as an example, right? Of course, you will have to use the variable you actually use. Most likely `$player_id_owner` from the example above..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
 $player_id_owner = $this->Player->find('first', array(
                      'fields' => array('id'),
                      'conditions' => array('Player.name' => $name)
                    ));
```

or try (you can also use your variable instead of yourname)

```
'conditions' => array('Player.name LIKE' => "%yourname%")
```

after that you can get the id with

```
$player_id_owner['Player']['id']
```

Comment: thanks, but i also tried find first function, still it doesn't pass the value to my variable.

Comment: yes but your given code has some syntax errors, give us some error code or debug messages pls

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'player_id_owner' cannot be null

'INSERT INTO `agileleagues`.`domain` (`name`, `player_type_id`, `color`, `abbr`, `description`, `player_id_owner`, `inactive`, `created`) VALUES ('TEST-2', 1, '#99CCFF', 'TD', 'TEST-2', NULL, '0', '2014-12-18 16:48:34')'

$player_id_owner is still null after that. thanks

Comment: thats the error because your $player_id_owner is null. you should make sure $player_id_owner is not null before your save() to database

Comment: Yes i know, and that's null because the query doesn't pass the value to my variable.

Comment: Are you sure there is a player with exactly that name? see my edit and try that

Comment: Hi! i tried your edit and put a hardcoded name on the condition and debug now returns this

array(
 'Player' => array(
  'id' => '46'
 )
)

now may i know how can i access the id?

Comment: like a normal array $player_id_owner['Player']['id']

Comment: btw i tried both rawsql and cakephp find but i got different output, may i know why?

using
`$player_id_owner = $this->Activity->query('Select player.id from player where player.name = ?', array($Player_name));`

i got this on my debug()
array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'player' => array(
   'id' => '46'
  )
 )
)

while using this

`$player_id_owner = $this->Player->find('first', array(
                      'fields' => array('id'),
                      'conditions' => array('Player.name LIKE' => $Player_name)
                    ));`
it returns this

array(
 'Player' => array(
  'id' => '46'
 )
)

Comment: why? you get the same if. if you mean the [0] its not in your Player->find() because you search 'first' so you have only one entry. if you search for 'all' you get beginning [0]

Comment: what i mean is that
where does array ((int) 0 come from?
array( (int) 0 => array( 'player' => array( 'id' => '46' ) ) )
while the cakephp find only returns this;
( 'Player' => array( 'id' => '46' ) )

Comment: thats what i just explained. 0 is the index for that array in the array. As you search for 'first' cake knows that there is only 1 entry so it doesnt create another index like 0, 1, 2, .... for your returns

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me, one more request sorry can you give me some tutorials beside the cakebook because i am new in cakephp and i want to have a tutorial with a lot of samples thanks.

Comment: the cookbook is the only resource you need tbh. start with understanding every step from the tutorials. not only doing those but understanding whats done and how it works is the key to success! http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

Comment: Thank you very much ruscher, sorry if i cant vote up  but you've been a big help for me.